# Пунктуация в предложении "Но люди(, /—) они (,) не меняются."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

Наткнулся в статье на достаточно интересное предложение, но, несмотря на некоторые осложнения предложения обращениями и уточняющими словами, захотел разобраться: как же будет правильно поставить запятые? 
   Я немного интерпретировал предложение, чтобы соблюдать некое табу ради политкорректности, оставив саму спорную ситуацию в пунктуации

Но люди, они, не меняются.
Но люди, они не меняются.

Более удачным, если не единственно правильным, я считаю второй вариант написания, но хотелось бы прочитать пояснение или объяснение альтернативного варианта пунктуации, например, с тире (но люди — они не меняются), а также узнать, чем является местоимение "они" в предложении при правильной расстановке запятых и почему какой-либо вариант некорректен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В указанном предложении возможны варианты пунктуации (в зависимости от смысла).

1. *Люди* — обращение, которое необходимо выделить запятыми.
   **Но, люди, они не меняются.**
2. *Но люди* — именительный темы, тогда пунктуация будет такой.
   **Но люди — они не меняются.**

При именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире:
*Дорога в дождь — она не сладость, дорога в дождь — она беда* (Евт.).

[Знаки препинания при именительном темы](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110)

Допустимо и написание с запятой, но тогда будет очень похоже на обращение.
(Но люди, они не меняются.)

P. S. Из Вашего заголовка: *“Но люди(, /—) они (,) не меняются.”*
Точка ставится **после** закрывающих кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

***Но люди, они не меняются*.**

**Смысл здесь представляется единственным**: это предложение с именительным темы.

**Именительный темы**  называет тему предложения. Эта структура может быть отдельным предложением или входит в состав предложения как обособленный член. Для обособления используется **тире или запятая.**

**Запятая** больше подходит для нераспространенного предложения с личным местоимением, в тоже время при выборе знака надо учитывать контекст.

Правило: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется **личное или указательное местоимение** в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире: Тягач — он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко — тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь — она не сладость, дорога в дождь — она беда (Евт.).

Примечание. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание с запятой: Врач, он ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.).